# ardu pilot mavlink

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect ardu pilot mega to ROS on ubuntu. I believe it has to be done using mavlink-ros-pkg but there is absolutely no documentation on how to get it running. Has anyone done this before? I would really appreciate if I could get some pointers. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11993/ardu-pilot-mavlink/) by [Ryuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1407/ryuu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on 2012-07-21**:
Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2690/is-ros-mavlink-pkg-supported-under-electric) is as far as I got (not very far.)

However, I just needed to get raw sensor data off of my APM-based quadrotor so I ended up writing a simple node that reads the RAW_GPS MAVLink message type and posts a GPSFix message.

You might find [this post](http://diydrones.com/forum/topics/how-do-i-get-lat-lon-data-from-apms-telemetry-module) useful to get started.

It's always best to reuse code (ie get ros-mavlink-pkg working) than to reinvent the wheel--but if it turns out ros-mavlink-pkg is dead, it's fairly trivial to get data out of MAVLink.

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1